# Basic usage of the type() function to determine the data type of object

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am really a beginner and I've been trying to understand the type() function used to determine the data type of certain object in Python.

Let's say I have this really simple function:

```
def TypeFunction():
    x = [1, 2, 3]
    y = 23
    z = 22
    print(type(x))


TypeFunction()
```

The output of the execution of this function will be (I am using PyCharm):

```
**<class 'list'>**

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The type() function has returned "list" as the data type of the variable "x".
However, I am not able to find if it is possible to use the type() function to determine the type of multiple objects. What I presume could be possible:

`type(object0, object1, object2)`

Is it possible in some way just like this one or I should create type() function for each object I want to determine its data type, separately? I was not able to find the answer myself in the documentation.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `type()` can take three arguments, but this makes a new class object.

Comment: `type(x)` `type(y)`  `type(z)` will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a loop:

```
def TypeFunction():
    x = [1, 2, 3]
    y = 23
    z = 22
    for i in [x, y, z]:
        print(type(i))
TypeFunction()
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Going back to the drawing board with loops now!

Answer (score 1):

You could define `TypeFunction` in such a way that it takes multiple objects and returns their types:

```
def TypeFunction(*objects):
    print(*(type(obj) for obj in objects), sep='\n')

TypeFunction(x, y, z)

# Output:
<class 'list'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that passing multiple arguments to the built-in type function has different meaning.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

To get the type of multiple objects, you would need a loop and pass individual object to the "type" function as described in previous answers.